# Loading certify SSL certificate into Netty engine

Tags: netty

I'm using the SSL example located in Netty example code folder:

```
String keyStoreFilePath = System.getProperty("keystore.file.path");
String keyStoreFilePassword = System.getProperty("keystore.file.password");

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(keyStoreFilePath);
ks.load(fin, keyStoreFilePassword.toCharArray());

// Set up key manager factory to use our key store
// Assume key password is the same as the key store file
// password
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
kmf.init(ks, keyStoreFilePassword.toCharArray());
```

I generated my own keystore using:

> /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/keytool -genkey -keystore SrvKeystore
>   -keyalg RSA

And everything is working great!!

However I now want to use an official certificate provided to me by comodo (https://secure.comodo.com/)

They obviously provide 3 files type: .csr, .crt and .key

Please advise which file should point to keystore.file.path and which to keystore.file.password

Maybe I need to do something else?

Comment: The solution is provided in this [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Generating_a_Private_Key_and_a_Keystore)

Answer (score 5):

Comodo is giving you the certificate and private key in a format most friendly for web servers (like Apache and nginx).

There are two ways of resolving this issue:

(1) Import the certificate chain (.crt) and private key (.key) into a jks or pkcs 12 key store (using keytool or openssl).

(2) Use the java CertificateFactory to read the cert and the bouncycastle PEMReader to read the private key then wrap this in your own key manager (which you can pass to the SSLContext).

Answer (score 0):

The basic information required for importing a CA authorized certificate is available here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html

**Importing Certificates**

To import a certificate from a file, use the -import command, as in

```
keytool -import -alias joe -file jcertfile.cer
```

This sample command imports the certificate(s) in the file jcertfile.cer and stores it in the keystore entry identified by the alias joe.

You import a certificate for two reasons:

1. to add it to the list of trusted certificates,
2. or
   to import a certificate reply received from a CA as the result of submitting a Certificate Signing Request (see the -certreq command) to that CA.